# Align equation to bracket in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment, equations

I need to align the second equation to the left, do you have any advice on how to do it?
Already tried through the align left(Alt+L), and inserting ”&” before the second equation.

[image]

Comment: Please post a small Word file with your equation.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you got the double-height curly bracket in the first place. Here is a way to do it starting from scratch.

From [this Microsoft Answers article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/make-left-curly-bracket-encompass-three-lines/6130da27-b599-4be2-b4e2-975a1f51ab21):

> - Press Alt+= to insert an equation box.
> - On the Equation Tools tab, click the Bracket button. Scroll down the gallery and click the icon for the single left bracket, which is accompanied by a little placeholder box.
> - Click inside the placeholder box. On the Equation Tools tab, click the Matrix button and click the icon for the two boxes set up vertically. Now your placeholder box has turned into two placeholder boxes, and the bracket has stretched to the proper height.
> - Right-click any of the two placeholders, click Column Alignment, and click Left.
> - Click in each of the two placeholder boxes in turn and type the [content] that you want there.

Answer (score 2):

Press **Alt + =** to insert an equation box. Or for mac user may use **Ctlr + =**.

Then, write

**\cases (&sin⁡(\alpha-\varphi)=0 \Rightarrow \alpha-\varphi-0@&-l_m e^(t/T_a )=0 \Rightarrow l_m=0)**

Answer (score 1):

Add spaces at the end of the second equation.

The entire string will stay centered, but the relevant equation will be shifted leftwards due to the introduction of space characters.